# Index with multiple iterators in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator

I have the following loop which works great:

```
@publishers.each do |proj, vp|
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
@publishers.each_with_index do |proj, vp, i|
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `vp`?  Where does it come from and how is it associated with `@publishers`?  Is it a property of a publisher?  Is it in a separate array?

Comment: looks like `@publichers` is a multidimansional Array `[[1,2], [3,4]...]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@publishers.each_with_index do |(proj, vp), i|
```